# How to get an android app listed in Assist app under Assist & voice input options

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I have the app which  converts speech to text.But i want the behavior to be like of Google assist app i.e i want my app to be invoked when there is trigger for Default voice assist app.Currently my app is not being listed in Assist app under Assist & voice input options.
Kindly help me out what changes can be made in existing below code so that it gets listed in the Assist app option and the phone takes it as default app. 
Thanks in advance.

//mainactivity.java

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
   // import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView txtSpeechInput;
private ImageButton btnSpeak;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
    btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);


    // hide the action bar
    //getActionBar().hide();
   // getSupportActionBar().hide();
    promptSpeechInput();

   /* btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
         }
       });*/

   }

/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
   private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,        Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

   /**
    * Receiving speech input
    * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

    }
}

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
     }

   }
```

---

//manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.gda6kor.speech3">

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_VOICE_INTERACTION"></uses-permission>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND"></action>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
 </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding those line to the intent filter for the activity:

```xml
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```